# authorized request to rails api not working on render server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, jwt, authorization, rails-api

Working from a Vue front end with a Rails API, I am attempting to implement following/unfollowing. this works fine on my local machine, but on my Render server, I am getting the message `Filter chain halted`, without the follow being created.

I thought/think this might be an environment vars issue, but I have checked the secret_key and confirmed via the rails console that JWT.decode is working. The request headers include the correct token as well.

Server log is:

```
Apr 5 01:21:16 PM  I, [2023-04-05T17:21:16.175314 #73]  INFO -- : [61a6e555-e384-49d0-bac6-27b8aaaece9a] Started POST "/authors/1e6935d8-7b95-4d72-bb76-1d8f8a535e70/follow" for 172.70.114.157 at 2023-04-05 17:21:16 +0000
Apr 5 01:21:16 PM  I, [2023-04-05T17:21:16.176134 #73]  INFO -- : [61a6e555-e384-49d0-bac6-27b8aaaece9a] Processing by AuthorsController#follow as */*
Apr 5 01:21:16 PM  I, [2023-04-05T17:21:16.176184 #73]  INFO -- : [61a6e555-e384-49d0-bac6-27b8aaaece9a]   Parameters: {"id"=>"1e6935d8-7b95-4d72-bb76-1d8f8a535e70"}
Apr 5 01:21:16 PM  header is eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiYzJhZWI3NDEtM2YzNS00NjA5LThhNDctYzgwMDc4OWRlOTU3IiwiZXhwIjoxNjgwNzk4ODUzfQ.rwqS6UHmtbH8NoC6dYphlPPtnotMhY0jmsXF_xae3sE
Apr 5 01:21:16 PM  decoding token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiYzJhZWI3NDEtM2YzNS00NjA5LThhNDctYzgwMDc4OWRlOTU3IiwiZXhwIjoxNjgwNzk4ODUzfQ.rwqS6UHmtbH8NoC6dYphlPPtnotMhY0jmsXF_xae3sE
Apr 5 01:21:16 PM  I, [2023-04-05T17:21:16.179648 #73]  INFO -- : [61a6e555-e384-49d0-bac6-27b8aaaece9a] Filter chain halted as :authorize_request rendered or redirected
Apr 5 01:21:16 PM  I, [2023-04-05T17:21:16.179767 #73]  INFO -- : [61a6e555-e384-49d0-bac6-27b8aaaece9a] Completed 401 Unauthorized in 4ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Allocations: 598)
```

Here is the Authors Controller:

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  # skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  before_action :find_author, except: [:index]
  before_action :authorize_request, except: [:index, :show, :followers]

  def index
    @authors = Author.all
    render json: @authors.to_json( :include => [:followers]), status: :ok
    
  end

  def show
    render json: @author.to_json( :include => [:followers]), status: :ok
  end

  def follow
    if @current_user
      @current_user.followeds << @author
      render json: @current_user
    else
      render json: { errors: 'No current user' }
    end
  end

  def unfollow
    @current_user.followed_authors.find_by(followed_id: @author.id).destroy
  end

  def followers
    @followers = @author.followers
                        # .paginate(page: params[:page])
    render json: @followers, status: :ok
  end

  private

  def find_author
    @author = Author.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      render json: { errors: 'Author not found' }, status: :not_found
    end
end
```

Authorize-request action in Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API

  def not_found
    render json: { error: 'not_found' }
  end

  def authorize_request
    header = request.headers['Authorization']
    header = header.split(' ').last if header
    puts "header is #{header}"
    begin
      @decoded = JsonWebToken.decode(header)
      puts "decoded header is #{@decoded}"
      puts "user id is: #{@decoded[0]['user_id']}"
      @current_user = User.find(@decoded[0]['user_id'])
      puts "current_user is #{@current_user}"
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      render json: { errors: e.message }, status: :unauthorized
    rescue JWT::DecodeError => e
      render json: { errors: e.message }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end
end
```

and JsonWebToken.rb:

```
class JsonWebToken
  # SECRET_KEY = Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base

  def self.encode(payload, exp = 24.hours.from_now)
    payload[:exp] = exp.to_i
    JWT.encode(payload, ENV['SECRET_KEY'])
  end

  def self.decode(token)
    puts("decoding token: #{token}")
    decoded = JWT.decode(token, ENV['SECRET_KEY'])
    puts("decoded is #{decoded}")
    return decoded
  end
end
```

Comment: You are rendering something in your filter, I suppose in a before_action. Post AuthorsController code

Comment: controller added above. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: post authorize_request  code too. It is failing authorizing the request and rendering the response before the actual execution of follow, but Filter chain halted is just a warning

Comment: Just  a little heads up: `@current_user.followed_authors.find_by(followed_id: @author.id).destroy` will potentially cause a NoMethod error if it was to return nil. This can happen for example in the classic double click scenario where two requests are fired at almost the same time and one destroys the record before the other is processed. Use `find_by!(followed_id: @author.id)` which will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` instead.

Comment: @Vi - added the authorize_request code. max - Thanks! I'll make that adjustment.

Comment: code is fine. Check if token is expired or all users are right

Comment: yes. suddenly working in production now. thanks.